# update instance variable without updating the model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, instance-variables

I have the following model...

```
ItemAttribute(id: integer, name: string count: integer)
```

In my controller I want to set a custom amount for count that I can use within my view...

```
@building = ItemAttribute.find_by_name("wall")
# the following line of code updates the model as well as the instance variable (not what I want)
@building.update_attribute(:count,10)
# the following line of code doesn't update the model (desired), but the value also resets back to the model's value in the view (not desired)...
@buildings.find_by_name("wall").count = 10
```

I'm using the count attribute in a loop in the view. The wall instance happens to be a special case, which is why I want to update the attribute only within the view.

Comment: what do you mean with "update the model", an update on database?

Comment: yes, exactly. No update on the database, but be able to update the instance variable's count.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set an instance variable in the controller and access that in the view.

```
@building = ItemAttribute.find_by_name("wall")
@count = 10
```

Then in your view access @count. That instance variable just lives for the request, and is available to the controller and the view.

Not sure what your last line is trying to do, it's assigning 10 to the count of a list of active record objects.

To get 10 Walls

```
@buildings = Building.find_by_name("wall").limit(10)
```

To get buildings where name == 'walls' and count == 10

```
@buildings = Building.where(name: "wall", count: 10)
```